# Booking.com API not taking city ISO code

Tags: php

I have found that for booking.com API call, it requires a parameter named city_ids which is minus six - digit number (-xxxxxx). Is there any way to call those API via city ISO2 or ISO3 code rather than city_ids.

Comment: which endpoint of booking.com api you are calling ? https://distribution-xml.booking.com/2.0/json/cities?languages=en&rows=10 ?

Comment: Please, try to be more clear with your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

What error you get it? Hmmm, looks that you are doing something wrong. Please fallow the [link to api](https://connect.booking.com/user_guide/site/en-US/b_xml-countries/) and you have example how to call (Dont forget to do authetication).

**Response Example**

```
<countries>
  <country countrycode="AD" name="Andorra" />
  <country countrycode="AE" name="United Arab Emirates" />
  <!-- example output. Use the API for a complete updated list -->
</countries>
<!-- RUID: [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==] -->
```